# Measure preserving transformation $T([a,b])\subset P$ if $\lambda(P)=\lambda([a,b])$

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

"Suppose that a measurable subset $P \subset [0,1]$ and the interval $I = [a,b] \subset [0,1]$ are such that

$\lambda(P) = \lambda(I)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Show that there exists a measure-preserving transformation

$T : [0,1] \to [0,1]$, i.e. $λ \circ T ^{-1} = \lambda$, such that $T(I) \subseteq P$ and $T$ is one-to-one (injective) outside a set of measure zero."

only hints please.

**Attempt**

1)The $T(x)=\lambda([0,x]\cap [a,b])$ if $x\in [a,b]$ and $b-a+\lambda([0,x]\setminus [a,b])$ if $x\notin [a,b]$ is measure preserving and injective outside a set of measure zero. However, it obviously might no map in P.

2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the (complete) total ordering of the reals and the fact that the Lebesgue measure is non-atomic.  Your (almost everywhere) one-to-one correspondence would match a point $x\in P$ with a point $y\in [a,b]$ if $\lambda([0,x]\cap P)=\lambda([0,y]\cap [a,b])$.